# Why Bayesian optimization in its simplest form only works for low dimensional optimization?

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization

This is what I learned from the class on how posterior is updated for Gaussian process:
[image]

It seems the computational cost of the matrix inversion only scales with the size of K_t, which depends on the number of data points x rather than the dimension of x. Intuitively I can see in higher dimensional space there are more degrees of freedom so more data points are needed to reduce those uncertainties and K_t becomes larger, but is there some formula from which we can directly see how the computation scales with dimensionality?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your question boils down to _"how does the computational cost of matrix inversion depend on the size of the matrix?"_. Note that the answer can be different for dense and sparse matrices.

Comment: I understand the computational cost of matrix inversion is O(n^3) when there is no structural properties to exploit. My question is more on is there a formula that tells us why high dimensional BO is costly as opposed to just the 'the higher dimension, the more data are needed' intuition